# Epoch Time Sorter

Tags: c, epoch

I am facing the following problem. I have some input based on epoch time, how to sort them on per day basis.

The overall aim of the program is to produce a summarized report on
url hit count, sorted from highest hit count to lowest count, organized
daily (use GMT) with the earliest date appearing first. Are there any libraries in C, I can use to sort the epoch time on per day basis

```
1407564301|www.nba.com
1407478021|www.facebook.com
1407478022|www.facebook.com
1407481200|news.ycombinator.com
1407478028|www.google.com
1407564301|sports.yahoo.com
1407564300|www.cnn.com
1407564300|www.nba.com
1407564300|www.nba.com
1407564301|sports.yahoo.com
1407478022|www.google.com
1407648022|www.twitter.com
```

Output

```
08/08/2014 GMT
www.facebook.com 2
www.google.com 2
news.ycombinator.com 1
08/09/2014 GMT
www.nba.com 3
sports.yahoo.com 2
www.cnn.com 1
08/10/2014 GMT
www.twitter.com 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a hash table (or something similar). [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) you can find more details, I'll give you just a basic explanation and how this can be applied in your case.

A hash table is used to classify data using a hash function. Basically, imagine you have some buckets, each labeled with some value. Take a data entry, run it through the hash function and place it in the bucket with the same value as the one returned by the hash function. Obviously, in your case, the hash function needs to be one that maps epoch time to day. There are many ways to do this, but probably the simplest is to use the standard function [strftime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/?kw=strftime), that converts a timestamp to a date in whatever format you want and use it for your hash function.

Of course, you would probably want to dynamically allocate those "buckets" (which are basically some data structures that contain an array of urls, probably), in order to optimize memory usage.